# Creating a multiprocessing queue throws an error

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I wrote a very simple program to try to demonstrate multiprocessing queues. However, it throws an error when the queue is created.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
q = mp.Queue() #error right here
q.put(1)
print(q.get())
```

I get this message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\mptest.py", line 2, in <module>
    q = mp.Queue()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 200, in Queue
    from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 22, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.connection import Pipe
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 21, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name Random
```

I've never seen this happen before and a google search yielded no results. It only happens when it's ran from the command line. It runs perfectly fine in IDLE. I'm using Python 3.3.2.

Comment: are you pasting the entire code? bec it says you imported Random which doesnt exists. Code works fine in cmd line as well as ide

Comment: @fscore Yes I am. That's what puzzles me.

Comment: does your code have anything called import Random?

Comment: @fscore No, I don't import random anywhere in the code. The 4 lines of code you see is all I have.

Comment: You probably have a file called `random.py` in the current directory or on your PATH.

Comment: @roippi I checked and there was. I renamed it to random-.py and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think its more to do with the version of python installed. I tried your code on cmd line as well as IDE but I got no errors. I have python 2.7 and 3.2 installed. But just to replicate your problem, I installed 3.3.2. I got the same error as you as I probably have random.py file too.